# The :first-letter reads <img> tag

Tags: html, image, css, pseudo-element

My paragraph `<p>` starts with some `<img>` in it, so `p:first-letter` doesn't apply to the text that comes after `<img>`

It does work if I remove the `<img>`.

https://jsfiddle.net/zg93usfn/

Comment: Yes... what did you expect? If you put an image in there, then `::first-letter` no longer applies.

Comment: Why do you need to put an image in your paragraph if you just put a line break after the image. Why not put the image outside and above the paragraph without a line break.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not possible

See [w3.org](https://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Selectors/pseudo-elements/:first-letter)

> The ::first-letter pseudo-element represents the first letter of an
>   element, **if it is not preceded by any other content (such as *images* or
>   inline tables)** on its line.

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap your text to any neutral html tag and then use letter spacing. This is only one way to solve this problem using CSS.